# Objeto query Genexus

Tags: genexus

tengo un WP con un objeto query en el que le cargo los datos a través de un procedimiento.

El problema que estoy teniendo es que solo logre actualizar la query haciendo un call al al WP, el tema es que necesito guardar unas variables en Seccion y si hago un Call del WP esos datos los pierdo, hay alguna otra manera de refrescar una query?

Probe con refresh y nada...

Gracias !

Answer (score 1):

En algún evento de usuario podes poner:

QueryViewer1.Object = TuQuery()

Si tuviera parametros, podes enviárselos allí mismo....  con eso deberias lograr actualizarlo.

Comment: Muchas gracias !